Application of the Method of Steepest Descents to Exponential Integral
I am trying to develop an asymptotic expansion of the following integral using the method of steepest descents:
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t+1}e^{ix(t^3-3)}dt$$
I rearranged it into the form $\int e^{ix(t^3-3) - \ln(t+1)} dt$, where $\phi(t) = -\ln(t+1)$ and $\psi(t)=x(t^3-3)$, such that $\rho(t)=\phi(t)+i\psi(t)$.
When I solve for the critical points of $\phi(t)$, I get 3 long expressions for $t$. I am not sure if this is the way to proceed. What would be the correct way of going about this?

There is no need to put $(t+1)^{-1}$
into the exponential since it is independent of the large variable $x$. You have to consider the critical points of $\mathrm{i}(t^3−3)$.

By first substituting $s = t^3$ and then $u = -\mathrm{i}s$, and subsequently deforming the path of integration and applying Watson's lemma, we arrive at
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{t + 1}}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}x(t^3  - 3)} {\rm d}t}  &= {\rm e}^{ - 3{\rm i}x} \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{t + 1}}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}xt^3 } {\rm d}t} \\ & = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - 3{\rm i}x} }}{3}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{s^{ - 2/3} }}{{s^{1/3}  + 1}}{\rm e}^{\mathrm{i}xs} {\rm d}s} 
\\ & = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - 3{\rm i}x} }}{3}\int_0^{ - {\rm i}\infty } {\frac{{u^{ - 2/3} }}{{u^{1/3}  + {\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}/6} }}{\rm e}^{ - xu} {\rm d}u} \\ & = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - 3{\rm i}x} }}{3}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{u^{ - 2/3} }}{{u^{1/3}  + {\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}/6} }}{\rm e}^{ - xu} {\rm d}u} 
\\ & \sim \frac{{{\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}/6} }}{3}\Gamma \!\left( {\frac{1}{3}} \right)\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - 3{\rm i}x} }}{{x^{1/3} }}
\end{align*}
as $x\to+\infty$.
To obtain a complete asymptotic expansion, one can use
$$
\frac{{u^{ - 2/3} }}{{u^{1/3}  + {\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}/6} }}={\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}/6} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n {\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}n/6} u^{(n + 1)/3 - 1} } 
$$
as $u\to0^+$, together with Watson's lemma.

Could you explain what you mean by deforming the path? And how were the leading behavior and series derived - is it from a Taylor expansion?

Let $R>0$. By Cauchy's theorem, $$\int_0^R \frac{u^{-2/3}}{u^{1/3} + \mathrm{e}^{-\pi\mathrm{i}/6}}\mathrm{e}^{-xu} , \mathrm{d}u + \int_{C_R} \frac{u^{-2/3}}{u^{1/3} + \mathrm{e}^{-\pi\mathrm{i}/6}}\mathrm{e}^{-xu} , \mathrm{d}u + \int_{-\mathrm{i}R}^0 \frac{u^{-2/3}}{u^{1/3} + \mathrm{e}^{-\pi\mathrm{i}/6}}\mathrm{e}^{-xu} , \mathrm{d}u=0,$$ where $C_R$ is a circular arc joining $R$ and $-\mathrm{i}R$. The second integral vanishes as $R\to+\infty$, thus

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{u^{-2/3}}{u^{1/3} + \mathrm{e}^{-\pi\mathrm{i}/6}} \mathrm{e}^{-xu} , \mathrm{d}u = -\int_{-\mathrm{i}\infty}^0 \frac{u^{-2/3}}{u^{1/3} + \mathrm{e}^{-\pi\mathrm{i}/6}} \mathrm{e}^{-xu} , \mathrm{d}u = \int_0^{-\mathrm{i}\infty} \frac{u^{-2/3}}{u^{1/3} + \mathrm{e}^{-\pi\mathrm{i}/6}} \mathrm{e}^{-xu} , \mathrm{d}u.$$
The leading term follows from Watson's lemma (do some reading). The series follows easily from the Maclaurin series of $\frac{1}{1+x}$.
